# How to make 150+ certificates, each with a different name

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, data-merge

I have a "Certificate of Recognition" PSD file with a blank line for the name portion. Is there a way to input all the participants' names without duplicating a certificate for each person individually?

Comment: How would you imagine "inputing" any type without actually typing it? It has to be typed by someone somewhere in some application. Do you have a file that lists the names or something? Or do you just have a handwritten list? And why is this tagged for InDesign if you're working in Photoshop?

Comment: I would imagine having the script edit that text box, and yes I have a digital list of all the names. I was wondering if InDesign had a capability like this if I just converted the psd to a pdf, or any other format.

Answer (score 4):

Use InDesign for this. Link the PSD in InDesign as a background image, and overlay the names from a CSV list, which should be typed in the format below. Then use [Data Merge](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html) to set up importing the names and use a paragraph style to format these over your PSD background.

```
name
Anton
Gabriele
Carla
...
```

Comment: This also works in illustrator

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what other software you have.

You could do that in Indesign as Lucian mention or you could do that using Word pulling the names from Excel, or can be done in Corel Draw.

Google then your specific tutorial using this words:

- Mail Merge Word Excel
- Variable Data Word Excel

And you will get for example this:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Change the name of the aplication depending on what you have. You can use Free Software like Open Office too.

Comment: I first did not read the InDesign Tag, but I'll leave this for other users.